# Why is the material preview black?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I wanted to create a landscape material, but when I blend the two textures, the preview is just black.

[image]

Comment: May it be a cache issue or even a bug? I'm not really an expert about 3D modelling but this happened to me many times in UE4. I was trying to modify a material, preview turned black just like it happened to you, I assumed I did something wrong and tried to revert the changes, the preview remained black. Then I restarted the editor and re-imported the material from the original source. For some reason the preview was still black.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?